# Access the plot object by Seaborn to put in Plots.plot as a subplot

Tags: julia, seaborn, plots.jl

Julia v1.9.2
Plots v1.38.0
Seaborn v1.1.1

I am trying to combine a heatmap (sbplot) from Seaborn and a regular Plots.plot (hist) as below, but am getting
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching getindex(::Nothing, ::Int64)

```
using Seaborn
using Plots

sbplot = Seaborn.heatmap([1 1.5; 3 2.8])
hist = Plots.bar([1,1.5, 2.,7])
combo = Plots.plot(sbplot,hist,layout=(2,1))
```

sbplot has many attributes, and I have tried sbplot.figure, .plot, .get_figure, etc., but could not get a compatible object to put together with hist.  Any suggestions?  Thank you!

Comment: I haven't used Seaborn in Julia, but if it's not playing nicely with `Plots` then one workaround is to save the seaborn plot as a picture and then plot that picture using Julia `Plots`, which should allow you to combine them. I can provide a more concrete example if you want let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @kirklong for the suggestion! This workaround did work for me.

```
using Seaborn
using Plots
using Images

sbplot = Seaborn.heatmap([1 1.5; 3 2.8])
Seaborn.savefig("SBplot.png")
sbplot_Plots = Plots.plot(Images.load("SBplot.png")) # Load in and make it a Plots plot object

hist = Plots.bar([1,1.5, 2.,7])

heat_hist_plot = Plots.plot(sbplot_Plots, hist, layout = @layout([A{0.8h}; B]))
```